# WP disobeys disabling of the posts revision feature

Tags: functions, wp-config

I disabled the posts revision feature according to this [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Disable_Post_Revisions) by placing this code in the wp-config.php:

`define('WP_POST_REVISIONS', false );`

But revions are still being saved by the WP. Why?

I am using wp3.1.3 and Twenty Ten theme. I have couple of plugins, and disabling them does not resolve the issue.

Comment: so when you add this code does it still show the post revisions in the edit post single page view? If so this is because there are already revisions present. This will only activate on new posts. You can always go into your db and manually delete the revisions

Comment: @xLRDxREVENGEx
when I edit NEW post and and publish it, I see NEW revions listed in admin below the editor. I understand that the old revisions will be there, but I am talking about is the NEW ones being saved as well.

Comment: try fresh install

Comment: @xLRDxREVENGEx my WP3.1.3 is a fresh install (installed manually!!).

Comment: Are you inserting it in the right place and out lines are closed properly

Comment: @xLRDxREVENGEx I am inserting it in functions.php as indicated in my first post on top. That's how the WP codex suggets to use.

Comment: no this goes into your wp-config.php file

Comment: In the root of your wordpress directory is the wp-config.php file this is where it goes not your functions.php and your post above says wp-config.php

Comment: Sounds good. since i did not really answer the question can you give me an up vote on the solution at lease.

Comment: @xLRDxREVENGEx, I be glad to, but I don't know how to go about doing it. I don't quite understand many features of this website yet.

Comment: If you highlight the comment a flag and triangle appear click the triangle.

Comment: @xLRDxREVENGEx, when I click the "flag", I dont' see any "triangle".

Comment: then most likely you do not have the privileges yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wp-config.php` is suggested place for such definitions, because at any point later they might get replaced by default values during loading.

See [Editing wp-config.php](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php) in Codex for thorough instructions.

Also worth noting that it's commonly said like *add to the end*, but really definitions should go above this line:

```
/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */
```

Or, if it was removed for some reason, above:

```
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this instead `define('WP_POST_REVISIONS', 0);`
I am currently using this on my wp-config.php file and it is working on my blog. (:

Comment: thanks for the reply. I tried your suggestion, unfortunately it did not work for me.